# How do I make a custom title field in a SharePoint content type

Tags: content-type, site-column, title-column

I have a new site collection in SP2016 and want to use content types for several logs we will be using. I want to be able to take advantage of the menu associated with the "Title" column but want a column for "Decision Title," "Communication Title," etc. I assume I need to create a content type based on the Item/Title column but when I try to change the title it changes the root "Title" column for every list on the site collection.

It seems like it would be possible to do this but I'm not finding anything that will keep the menu and allow for the alternate name - any suggestions?

Thanks for your help.

Tammy

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only rename it at the list level. Now you are trying to rename the site column which will affect every list en library in your site collection.

In my view the only way forward is to create a new site column, add that to the custom content type. Then remove the required from the title column and hide it. See [Custom lists and mandatory 'Title' field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34577/custom-lists-and-mandatory-title-field)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, add a new field "something Title" to the content type, make it mandatory , hide the default title field. Remember to switch the link from the default title field to the new field. This can either be handled in the GUI or in powershell

Comment: How do you do that in the GUI? I thought at a minimum you needed SharePoint Designer to do that, and even then it’s editing CAML.